# Node Stream - Output multiple Transform streams to single PassThrough stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-streams

I periodically have to download/parse a bunch of Json data, about 1000~1.000.000 lines.

Each request has a chunk limit of 5000. So I would like to fire of a bunch of request at the time, stream each output through its own Transfomer for filtering out the key/value's and then write to a ***combined*** stream that writes its output to the database.

But with every attempt it doesn't work, or it gives errors because to many event listeners are set. What seems correct if I understand the the 'last pipe' is always the reference next in the chain.

Here is some code (changed it lot of times so could make little sense).

The question is: Is it bad practice to join multiple streams to one? Google also doesn't show a whole lot about it.

Thanks!

**brokerApi/getCandles.js**

```
// The 'combined output' stream
let passStream = new Stream.PassThrough();

countChunks.forEach(chunk => {
    let arr = [];
    let leftOver = '';
    let startFound = false;
    let lastPiece = false;
    let firstByte = false;
    let now = Date.now();

    let transformStream = this._client

        // Returns PassThrough stream
        .getCandles(instrument, chunk.from, chunk.until, timeFrame, chunk.count)
        .on('error', err => console.error(err) || passStream.emit('error', err))
        .on('end', () => {
            if (++finished === countChunks.length)
                passStream.end();
        })
        .pipe(passStream);

    transformStream._transform = function(data, type, done) {
        /** Treansform to typedArray **/

        this.push(/** Taansformed value **/)
    }
});
```

Extra - Other file that 'consumes' the stream (writes to DB)

**DataLayer.js**

```
    brokerApi.getCandles(instrument, timeFrame, from, until, count)
            .on('data', async (buf: NodeBuffer) => {
                this._dataLayer.write(instrument, timeFrame, buf);

                if (from && until) {
                    await this._mapper.update(instrument, timeFrame, from, until, buf.length / (10 * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT));
                } else {
                    if (buf.length) {
                        if (!from)
                            from = buf.readDoubleLE(0);

                        if (!until) {
                            until = buf.readDoubleLE(buf.length - (10 * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT));
                            console.log('UNTIL TUNIL', until);
                        }

                        if (from && until)
                            await this._mapper.update(instrument, timeFrame, from, until, buf.length / (10 * Float64Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT));
                    }
                }

            })
            .on('end', () => {
                winston.info(`Cache: Fetching ${instrument} took ${Date.now() - now} ms`);
                resolve()
            })
            .on('error', reject)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "bad practice"? Does approach at Question return expected result, or not? Have you tried using [web-streams-polyfill](https://github.com/creatorrr/web-streams-polyfill), which is based on the [Streams Standard](https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/)? Not sure why `nodejs` implements streams using an event based process, rather than `Promise` based process

Comment: No I can't get it to work, it does when it fires 2-3 request, but fails as soon as its more then 5.. With random sqlite errors (Node Buffer is corrupted).. So I wonder if its even the way to go, outputting multiple streams to a single stream (new to streams)

Comment: Why do you not concatenate the accrued typed arrays at completion of all stream instances?

Comment: That would go against the benefit of streaming is it not? Maybe I don't understand streams in general, but I don't want to wait until the full 5000 lines of JSON is parsed, but instead just parse the string on every data chunk.. So the database can just keep  on writing

Comment: Btw.. 5000 lines is a fictional number, lot of times its also 500.000 per request, so thats about 5MB ~ 10MB of data on every request... Other option is to use plain old 'onData()' callbacks, but thought streams would be nice :)

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve? Merge results into a single stream; or perform separate processes for each stream? The amount of data should not affect the outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the stream helpers from [highlandjs](http://highlandjs.org), e.g. (untested, pseudo code):

```
function getCandle(candle) {...}

_(chunks).map(getCandle).parallel(5000).pipe(...)
```

Comment: Looks good indeed, but are there really no 'vanilla' solutions to this? Just combining multiple input streams into a single output stream?

Comment: A few points about your approach (the vanilla solution): a) `_transform()` must call `done()` to indicate its done pushing chunks. b) `this._client.getCandles()` is probably returning a `ReadableStream` and if you want to transform it's output, you should pipe it to a transform stream (see `through2` package). c) to combine manually, you should queue up transformed candles and create a `ReadableStream` with a `_read` implementation which will pull from the queue and `push` to itself.  Need a queue because `push` shouldn't be called outside `_read`.

Comment: and don't forget to set objectMode as appropriate.